# Javascript quiz so when it reaches a full sycle of questions it stops

Tags: javascript

This may sound like a previous question I asked, but it was only partially answered. So I Want to go to the question I asked it to go to and start. Then Once it reaches the last question(#5) it goes back to the first question(#1), and when it reaches the starting question it would stop. I tried doing this in the following code but It would not work. I am 11 and started programming about 9 months ago.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Are you smarter than a 5th Grader?!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body onload="starter()" bgcolor="lightblue">
    <h1><marquee><font color="red">Make Trivia Great Again!</font></marquee></h1>
    <h2><em><center>Are You Smater Than a 5th Grader?</center></em></h2>
    <button onclick="sc()">Start</button>
    <br>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset Score</button>
    <script>
      function starter() {
        setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
        setTimeout("minusCounter()", 101)
      }

      function reset() {
        setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
        localStorage.clickcount = -1

      }

      function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 0;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
        } else {}
      }

      function minusCounter() {

        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) - 1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 0;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
        } else {}
      }

      if (!("scramble" in Array.prototype)) {
        Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "scramble", {
          enumerable: false,
          value: function() {
            var o, i, ln = this.length;
            while (ln--) {
              i = Math.random() * (ln + 1) | 0;
              o = this[ln];
              this[ln] = this[i];
              this[i] = o;
            }
            return this;


          }
        });
      }
      var quiz = [{
        "question": "When was the first apple computer made?",
        "choices": ["1904", "1976", "1978", "2004"],
        "correct": ["1976"]
      }, {
        "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
        "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak", "Martin Shaba"],
        "correct": "Bill Gates"
      }, {
        "question": "What was your first dream?",
        "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
        "correct": "8 bits"
      }, {
        "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
        "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
        "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
      }, {
        "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
        "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
        "correct": "Carbon Copy"
      }, {
        "question": "What is the full for of IP",
        "choices": ["Internet provider", "Intenet Port", "Other", "Internet Protocol"],
        "correct": "Other"
      }]

      function stop() {
        alert("stopped")
      }

      function setter() {
        for (x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
          uc()
        }
      }

      function sc() {
        var q = prompt("start question #", "")
        if (q >= 6) {
          alert("please pick a valid question")
          sc()
        } else if (q <= 5 && q > 0) {
          ec()
        } else if (q == 0) {
          alert("please pick a valid question")
          sc()
          return;

        } else {
          alert("Please pick a valid question"), sc()
        }

        function ec() {
          for (x = q; x < 7; x++) {
            if (x == 6) {
              setter()

            } else if (x == x) {
              return;
            } else {
              uc()
            }
          }

          function uc() {
            quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
            var ans = ""

            function myFunction(item, index) {
              ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
            }
            quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
            var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
            if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
              alert("Correct!")
              clickCounter()
            } else if (y == "Cancel") {
              alert("canceled")
              page.reload()
            } else {
              alert("Wrong! Please Try Again.");
              repeat()
            }

            function repeat() {
              quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
              var ans = ""

              function myFunction(item, index) {
                ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
              }
              quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
              var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
              if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
                alert("Correct!,Good Job")
                clickCounter()
              } else if (y == "Cancel") {
                alert("canceled")
              } else {
                alert("Sorry! \nThe right answer is " + quiz[x].correct);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very impressive coding for an 11 year old. The problem you are facing here is function and variable scope. Functions have been nested inside other functions when they shouldn't be. Also when you are using a variable that are used in other functions you must declare it globally (although this can be a bad idea sometimes).

Start here to learn more about scope: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Keep up the coding :)

Your code is fixed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Are you smarter than a 5th Grader?!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body onload="starter()" bgcolor="lightblue">
    <h1><marquee><font color="red">Make Trivia Great Again!</font></marquee></h1>
    <h2><em><center>Are You Smater Than a 5th Grader?</center></em></h2>
    <button onclick="sc()">Start</button>
    <br>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset Score</button>
    <script>

        function starter() {
            setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
            setTimeout("minusCounter()", 101)
        }

        function reset() {
            setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
            localStorage.clickcount = -1

        }

        function clickCounter() {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

              if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
              } else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 0;
              }
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
            } else {}
        }

        function minusCounter() {

            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

                if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                    localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) - 1;
                } 
                else {
                    localStorage.clickcount = 0;
                }

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
            } else {

            }
        }

        if (!("scramble" in Array.prototype)) {
            Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "scramble", {
              enumerable: false,
              value: function() {
                var o, i, ln = this.length;
                while (ln--) {
                  i = Math.random() * (ln + 1) | 0;
                  o = this[ln];
                  this[ln] = this[i];
                  this[i] = o;
                }
                return this;


              }
            });
        }

        var quiz = [{
            "question": "When was the first apple computer made?",
            "choices": ["1904", "1976", "1978", "2004"],
            "correct": ["1976"]
          }, {
            "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
            "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak", "Martin Shaba"],
            "correct": "Bill Gates"
          }, {
            "question": "What was your first dream?",
            "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
            "correct": "8 bits"
          }, {
            "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
            "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
            "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
          }, {
            "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
            "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
            "correct": "Carbon Copy"
          }, {
            "question": "What is the full for of IP",
            "choices": ["Internet provider", "Intenet Port", "Other", "Internet Protocol"],
            "correct": "Other"
          }];

        function stop() {
            alert("stopped")
        }

        function setter() {
            for (x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
              uc();
            }
        }


        var q;
        function sc() {
            q = prompt("start question #", "")
            if (q >= 6) {
              alert("please pick a valid question")
              sc()
            } else if (q <= 5 && q > 0) {
              ec()
            } else if (q == 0) {
              alert("please pick a valid question")
              sc()
              return;

            } else {
              alert("Please pick a valid question"), sc()
            }
        }

        var x;
        function ec() {
            console.log('ec');
            for (x = q; x < 7; x++) {
               if (x == 6) {
                    setter()

                    //} else if (x == x) {
                    //  return;
                } else {
                      uc()
                }
            }
        }

        function uc() {
            console.log('uc');
            quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
            var ans = ""

            function myFunction(item, index) {
              ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
            }
            quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
            var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
            if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
              alert("Correct!")
              clickCounter()
            } else if (y == "Cancel") {
              alert("canceled")
              page.reload()
            } else {
              alert("Wrong! Please Try Again.");
              repeat()
            }
        }

        function repeat() {
            quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
            var ans = ""

            function myFunction(item, index) {
            ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
            }
            quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
            var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
            console.log(y);
            console.log(quiz[x].correct);
            if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
                alert("Correct!,Good Job")
                clickCounter()
            } else if (y == "Cancel") {
                alert("canceled")
            } else {
                alert("Sorry! \nThe right answer is " + quiz[x].correct);
            }
        }


    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much